# Custom HTML element compatibility

Tags: jquery, html

I want to define custom HTML elements to declare certain blocks in the HTML. These blocks can then be found by jquery. For example:

```
    <gcms-block id="1">
        ...
    </gcms-block>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("gcms-block[id='1']").html("new content");
        });
    </script>
```

The `gcms-block` are **only** used by the jquery method to get or set the content in the block (so I don't want to apply styles or something like that on the element). Due the limits of a CMS I'm using I can't just add an id to a `<div>` element and use that to get the block.

So my question is if this approach is compatible with multiple browsers? And if not, what is a better way to do this?

Comment: So you can define a new HTML element, but you can't just use an `id` on a `div`. Why is that? And older browser will not render this, not to mention it is not valid HTML.

Comment: Because of the template engine the CMS uses.. It renders blocks on a page and not all of these blocks have a container surrounding them with a corresponding id. So to access them with JQuery I'll either have to adjust all block templates (which are 100+). Or I just add the gcms-block tag with id attribute to the rendered block.

Answer (score 0):

Although browsers support custom elements, you are breaking the "standard" if you close to do this and it's not considered the best practice.

If you're restricted by the limitations of your CMS you may have no way around that.

If you are going to go the route of using non supported elements you may want to leave out special characters and keep things formatted like the defined html elements to keep them as close to the standard elements as possible.

Comment: These custom tags will only be rendered from within the admin panel. It indeed breaks the standard, but does that really matter if it's only used inside the admin panel?

Comment: It's just considered bad practice. The web page will render without any issues however it's not considered valid html

Comment: Hmm ok that's true. But other companies do use custom html tags (e.g facebook with a `<fb:fml>` or `<fb:profile-pic>` tag). That's why I'm considering using it myself

Comment: we use custom elements all the time with angular without issue. Issues from using custom elements usually happen in older browsers. That said, i don't see why you cant just add a class to a div instead. ID and TagName aren't the only ways to select an element.